# How should I configure the vault server config file to make it respond to required headers

Tags: docker, rest, http-headers, listener, hashicorp-vault

I have vault docker container running successfully.

Below is my vault server config:

```
listener "tcp" {
  address = "0.0.0.0:8200"
  tls_disable = "false"
  tls_cert_file = "/localhost.crt"
  tls_key_file = "/localhost.key"
  tls_min_version = "tls12"
  tls_cipher_suites = <<EOF
    TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
    TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
    TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
    TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
    TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
    TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,
    TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
    TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
    TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
    TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
    TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
    TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
    TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
    TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
    EOF
  tls_prefer_server_cipher_suites = "true"
}

storage "consul" {
  address = "consul:8500"
  path = "vault/"
}

ui = "true"
log_level = "Debug"
```

I need to add headers for server config file like Content-Type, iFrame related headers to increase the security. But no where inside vault documentation I am able to see the option for adding the headers. Please help me to configure the vault server headers.
Previously I had done the same thing with nginx.conf, where add_headers was used to make necessary changes to nginx server config file. In the similar way is there any provision for adding headers in vault config.
Thank You

Comment: Would using the [/sys/config/ui](https://www.vaultproject.io/api-docs/system/config-ui) endpoint to set those extra headers be an option ?

Comment: I guess, but this option we should be enabling it externally by posting from user right after server is up and running? Just like nginx where we can modify the server config by adding these extra headers using command "add_header", checking for any provision given in vault config for the same.